# Printing 2 lines under user input?

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried printing 2 lines under the code the user enters from a text file.

my text file :

```
86947367
banana
5

78364721
apple
3

35619833
orange
2

84716491
sweets
8

46389121
chicken
10
```

So if the user enters e.g `46389121` then it will print

```
chicken
    10
```

I have tried :

```
file = 'read_it.txt'
user = input('Enter code')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate will count and keep track      of the lines
      if line == user:
            print("{}\n{}".format(lines[i+1], lines[i+2]))
```

but it gives me an output of blank lines , any help please ?

Comment: You need to indent your `if` block under your `for` loop to start with.

Comment: yh sry ( it is indented in main code)

Comment: Have you tried doing `if line.strip() == user`? Because it's probably not satisfying `if line == user` because `line` has a newline at the end while `user` probably doesn't

Comment: gives me error : string out of index range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stripping the line before comparing using `rstrip()`:

```
file = 'read_it.txt'
user = input('Enter code')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate will count and keep track      of the lines
      if line.rstrip() == user:
            print("{}\n{}".format(lines[i+1], lines[i+2]))
```

Keep in mind, that instead of loading all file at once, you can just iterate over it like so:

```
file = 'read_it.txt'
user = input('Enter code')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == user:
            print(next(f).rstrip())
            print(next(f).rstrip())
            break
```

---

The `rstrip()` function removes whitespace at the end of the string. Whitespace includes , `\n`, `\t`, `\r` etc.

Comment: thanks , the second one works great , this is the first time I have encountered the rstrip() function , can you explain what it does in this context ? And how can I get rid of the space in the output ?thank you.

Comment: why can i not set a variable to the print function ? When I do and try to print it out it gives me None